# Fatal Error: Call to undefined method FPDF

Tags: fatal-error, fpdf

I got this error message. Please help me solve that.

**Fatal error: Call to undefined method FPDF::check() in C:\xampp\htdocs\sikembul\application\views\viw_slip_gaji.php on line 38**

this my code

```
<?php
$GLOBALS['a']=2;
$GLOBALS['alpha']=3;
$GLOBALS['beta']=5;


function check($num)
{
    if ($num=="1")
    {
        global $a;
        global $alpha;
        global $beta;

        $total = $a*$alpha*$beta;
        $this->fpdf->Cell(50,5,'final',1,0,'L');
        $this->fpdf->Cell(8,5,'xx.',1,0,'L');
        $this->fpdf->Cell(20,5,$total,1,1,'R');
    }
    else 
    {
        global $a;
        global $alpha;
        global $beta;

        $total = $a-$alpha-$beta;
        $this->fpdf->Cell(50,5,'final',1,0,'L');
        $this->fpdf->Cell(8,5,'xx.',1,0,'L');
        $this->fpdf->Cell(20,5,$total,1,1,'R');
    }
}

$this->fpdf->FPDF('P','mm','A5');
$this->fpdf->SetMargins(10,10,10);
$this->fpdf->AddPage();
$this->fpdf->setFont('Times','B',9);
$this->fpdf->Cell(130,5,'Here Some Text to Display',0,1,'C');
$this->fpdf->check(1);

$this->fpdf->Output('generate.pdf','I');
?>
```

FYI, everything works fine when i disable the function. 
Thanks for all of the help and comments.

Comment: for one, you're calling a function that appears to be outside the class. All you'd need to do is change $this->fpdf->check(1) to check(1) and then either global the fpdf instance or pass the instance to the function

Comment: Kai Qing, could you fix my code please? 
I still do not understand..

Comment: I gave an example. No guarantees on it. It's supposed to be a suggestion and not really an official answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this. Passing the instance to the function may work. This is just a quick sample and may not work as expected, but it illustrates what I was suggesting in the comment.

```
<?php
$GLOBALS['a']=2;
$GLOBALS['alpha']=3;
$GLOBALS['beta']=5;


function check($num, &$fpdf)
{
    global $a;
    global $alpha;
    global $beta;

    if ($num=="1")
    {
        $total = $a*$alpha*$beta;
        $fpdf->Cell(50,5,'final',1,0,'L');
        $fpdf->Cell(8,5,'xx.',1,0,'L');
        $fpdf->Cell(20,5,$total,1,1,'R');
    }
    else 
    {
        $total = $a-$alpha-$beta;
        $fpdf->Cell(50,5,'final',1,0,'L');
        $fpdf->Cell(8,5,'xx.',1,0,'L');
        $fpdf->Cell(20,5,$total,1,1,'R');
    }
}

$this->fpdf->FPDF('P','mm','A5');
$this->fpdf->SetMargins(10,10,10);
$this->fpdf->AddPage();
$this->fpdf->setFont('Times','B',9);
$this->fpdf->Cell(130,5,'Here Some Text to Display',0,1,'C');
check(1, $this->fpdf);

$this->fpdf->Output('generate.pdf','I');
?>
```